# Composer alternately removes/reinstalls the same packages each time update is run

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

The basic problem is:

```
$ composer update
Package operations: 1 install, 3 updates, 1 removal
- Removing psr/http-client (1.0.0)
- Downgrading php-http/httplug (v2.0.0 => v1.1.0): Loading from cache
- Downgrading php-http/client-common (2.0.0 => 1.9.1): Loading from cache
- Downgrading php-http/curl-client (2.0.0 => v1.7.1): Loading from cache
- Installing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v1.1.1): Loading from cache
Writing lock file...etc

$ composer update
Package operations: 1 install, 3 updates, 1 removal
- Removing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v1.1.1)
- Installing psr/http-client (1.0.0): Loading from cache
- Updating php-http/httplug (v1.1.0 => v2.0.0): Loading from cache
- Updating php-http/curl-client (v1.7.1 => 2.0.0): Loading from cache
- Updating php-http/client-common (1.9.1 => 2.0.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file...etc
```

So each time I run update, it'll alternate between installing/removing the same packages, leaving it in a different end state each time.

Extract of composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/telescope": "^2.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.8",
    "sentry/sentry": "^2.0",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^1.0",
    "somsip/blc_knd": "dev-master",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^4.2",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "^4.2"
},
```

The only thing that is definitely broken is logging to Sentry. Tracing the issue takes me to a Promise being created for the async POST to the Sentry DSN and that's where it fails, which points in the general direction of the problem being rooted in the HTTP libraries that are being installed/removed. There's nothing I see in the composer.json for getsentry/sentry or getsentry/sentry-laravel packages that has changed recently, and no issues along these lines have been reported.

Is this something where there is an obvious approach to troubleshooting what Composer is doing, or do I live with it for a few days to see if some dodgy package somewhere gets fixed?

Later:

If I run 'composer update --no-dev' it doesn't exhibit this behaviour, which might suggest the conflict is in "require-dev". And because somsip/blc_knd is one of mine I'll fix up some dependencies in that first.

```
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.2",
    "beyondcode/laravel-query-detector": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.3",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.8",
    "laravel/dusk": "^5.0",
    "mayflower/php-codebrowser": "^2.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.1",
    "nunomaduro/larastan": "^0.3.17",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.5",
    "phploc/phploc": "^4.0",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.6",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
    "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "^4.1",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.4"
},
```

Final edit:

This has been condensed into a standalone composer.json that allows the problem to be reproduced. An issue has been created under the composer/composer package:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8306

It's likely there are two separate issues: there is a dependency conflict in a package, and composer is not handling the conflict nicely.

And the issue relating to Sentry is a known one and though it led to me finding the composer bug, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with it:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/issues/871

Comment: Do you have a custom package loading in your composer.json ? `"repositories": {`

Comment: It looks like you've got conflicting dependencies, but Composer should fail on that. It should not install packages and definitely not alternate between them. I'd take this up to the [official repo](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues)

Comment: Trying with that same `composer.json` (minus your `"somsip/blc_knd"` package), I can't repro.

Comment: @N69S - yes, I was just trying to post enough of it to make sense without putting too much that was not required.

Comment: @yivi - it's also happening on 3 other projects I updated at the same time. and on a clone of a bigger project. But these are all private repos so I can share the full codebase.

Comment: That's fine, but with the information here it's impossible to reproduce the problem, and thus to answer the question.

Comment: @Loek - I was looking for a way to troubleshoot it myself, but if taking it to composer/composer is the way to go, so be it. Thanks

Comment: @yivi - absolutely fair, and I suppose the real question was 'how can I troubleshoot it myself or should I just flag it as an issue with composer'

Comment: Although it's weird, can you post the output of `id` and `ls -l composer.lock` commands?

Comment: @meysam - permissions don't appear to be a thing as it can all be reproduced from a new folder containing the composer.json, which is available in full on the issue I've just created and updated in the question

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm this is proved as fixed in composer 2.0 given the closing comment on the bug ticket:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8306#issuecomment-597696922